# How to find the proper XPath for importxml to import this table in Google Sheets?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import the table on this website http://www1.hket.com/store/general/finance/web/hsioptions_day.html 
and have it automatically update.

I have tried several ways to import the table to the sheets using

```
importhtml("http://www1.hket.com/store/general/finance/web/hsioptions_day.html","table",1)
```

But it seems it is not a table.

I also tried to import the table using

```
importxml("http://www1.hket.com/store/general/finance/web/hsioptions_day.html",A1)
```

as the XPath contains double quote I define cell A1 = `//*[@id="table1"]/table`

But it seems the XPath is wrong and it doesn't work. I've got an empty content error.

I wonder if anyone could help me to import the table properly into the sheet. Once it can be properly imported, I will try using the google script to update it automatically, using this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijaj7CXSg-Q&ab_channel=ArgentEngineering

Would anyone give some ideas to me how to properly import this table to the sheet?

I am an absolute noob in this and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fear this won't work, your page is built with Javascript, which isn't supported by `IMPORTXML` (or by Google Sheets in general).

Comment: Do you know any way to scrap it? If googlesheet is not working, can you point me to something I can start with? Maybe thru a python script?I have no idea...

Comment: None that I know of, from the top of my head. If your site proposes an API, or a javascript-free version, you may try that. Other persons may have found a way around that, but the solutions I know just get the source of the page, not the result after javascript execution.

Answer (score 0):

all you can scrape from this site is:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www1.hket.com/store/general/finance/web/hsioptions_day.html", "//*")
```

[image: 0]

---

and/or also this:

```
=IMPORTDATA("http://www1.hket.com/store/general/finance/web/hsioptions_day.html")
```

[image: 0]

---

as already mentioned Google Sheets can't handle websites controlled via JavaScript

[image: 0]